# Format string within a method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-intl

I'm experiencing difficulties with two cases of string formatting:

1. When I need to provide a string (not a component) as a prop value to some component.

   Yes, I've found [(two) ways](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/749) how to achieve that, but both seem to be so ugly when writing in Typescript (due to unavoidable type check suppressions), so I would ask for another which is more idiomatic for this language.
2. When I need to format string programmatically within a component method. Didn't succeed to achieve that.

P.S. Is there more convenient internalisation library than React-Intl?

Answer (score 0):

Im using [react-redux-i18n](https://github.com/zoover/react-redux-i18n) which have the component  which work most of the time in string props (even though it returns translation) But you can also use I18n.t('translation_key')